# Preventing batch file formats in GPO

Tags: active-directory, gpo

Is it possible to disable AD users from saving a text file as a .bat format via GPO? If yes, how is it doable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specific where you wanted to prevent the saving of files, I will give a general answer.

1. You can users prevent from saving files with a specific extension (file screening) on network shares using something called [File Server Resource Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754810(v=ws.10).aspx).
2. You can prevent users from *executing* or *running* files having specific extensions through a GPO.
3. One cannot prevent a user from *saving* a file with a specific extension to their *own* workstation.

So, depending on the Microsoft technology you are using, and where the file is being saved, the overall answer is it depends.